# how to takes a entire available space in column in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, widget

I will explain with simple examble,

```
class Demo1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Flexible(
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: const [
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.image),
                title: Text('with shrinkwrap is true'),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
              ),
            ])),
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
            )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here the green colored container is not filling the remaining space, so how to fill the remaining area?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Try below code and just Remove your first `Flexible` Widget

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: const [
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.image),
          title: Text('with shrinkwrap is true'),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Thank you for responding quickly and this is OK for this example but if you add n items(items beyond the screen height) to listview it will throws overflow error ,so how can you solve it?

Comment: @guru Can you add your updated code with error?

Comment: just add 100 or above ListTile widget to Listview so you will get the overflow error

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SingleChildScrollView` instead of using ListView with `shrinkWrap: true`.

```dart
class Demo1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: const [
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.image),
                    title: Text('with shrinkwrap is true'),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
            )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You may also like [`CustomScrollView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) over `SingleChildScrollView` and `shrinkWrap:true`.

Answer (score 0):

Both `Flexible` and `Expanded` have flex value 1, so they both request 50% of the available space. So the `Container` child of `Expanded` takes fills only half space, while the `ListView`, a child of `Flexible`, also requests half the space but needs very little space.

You can make `Container` fill the available space by removing `Flexible`, so `Expanded` that wraps `Container` will get all the available space.